# Get base URL in a Magento xml

Tags: magento

I am trying to add a link to the `footer_menu` block through my `page.xml`:

```
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links-follow.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                    <label>Condiciones generales</label>
                    <url>legal</url>
                    <title>Condiciones generales</title>
                </action>
            </block>
```

But, obviously the path is relative to the page it is displayed on. Since the home url is bound to change (from being in `/foo/` to being in the root `/`) I would like to prepend the shop base url to make it work automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that adding `<urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />` to the mix does the job.
**It is crucial to follow the order of the elements** in able for it to work (quite confusing if you ask me).

```
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links-follow.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                    <label>Condiciones generales</label>
                    <url>legal</url>
                    <title>Condiciones generales</title>
                    <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />
                </action>
            </block>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps taking a look at [`Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links::addLink()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php#L85) and [`Mage_Core_Helper_Url::getHomeUrl()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php#L81) will reduce the confusion.

Comment: XML order of sibiling elements should not matter, no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

This method working fine

I am using `{{baseUrl}}` to get base url in layout .xml file for adding canonical url in customer/account/login url

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>canonical</rel>
        <href>{{baseUrl}}customer/account/login</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: my action method was setText so for what i needed worked out great, i used this method because i needed to set the crossorigin for the link and with addLinkRel method i was not able to.
`<action method="setText">
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <link rel="preload" href="{{baseUrl}}skin/frontend/....." crossorigin="anonymous">
                        ]]>
                </text>
            </action>`

Comment: Great.. Working fine for me. Thanks @shyopat.
I have wasted too much time to find a solution for dynamic url but didn't use `{{baseUrl}}`. It is working charm.